# What's wrong with my permissions in sudo gedit /etc/fstab?

Tags: mount, ntfs, fstab

I keep getting this error when trying to mount my secondary internal hdd...

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb
[mntent]: line 13 in /etc/fstab is bad
mount: can't find /dev/sdb in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

This is what my text editor shows when I enter sudo gedit /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2f16dad8-494b-4cce-b3d6-aead00238b17 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=e881ffcf-37ab-43d1-b1a4-eb00581b7110 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=543E2FD13E2FAB46 /dev/sdb /mnt/media_sdb1 ntfs-3g defaults 0 0

UUID=E46014BE6014997E /media/KILLUMINATI-ONE  ntfs-3g  defaults,umask=0022,fmask=0133  0  0
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the command you're using to mount your HDD to your post.

Answer (score 2):

This line is not correct

`UUID=543E2FD13E2FAB46 /dev/sdb /mnt/media_sdb1 ntfs-3g defaults 0 0`

Either you are identifying a partition based on UUID (like you did for `/`), either you're identifying it based on its name in  `/dev` (like `/dev/sdb1`).

On your line above, if the UUID is correct (check it with `sudo blkid /dev/sdb1`), just remove the `/dev/sdb`.

ps: your partition is most probably `/dev/sdb1` and not `/dev/sdb', as pointed out by [swisscheese](https://askubuntu.com/a/392032/211552).

Comment: /dev/sda1: UUID="2f16dad8-494b-4cce-b3d6-aead00238b17" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="e881ffcf-37ab-43d1-b1a4-eb00581b7110" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="I LOVE YOU !" UUID="543E2FD13E2FAB46" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdc2: LABEL="KILLUMINATI - ONE" UUID="E46014BE6014997E" TYPE="ntfs"

Comment: That's what Sudo Blkid says...

Comment: I did what you said and removed the dev/sdb portion... But now I get this error.......

Comment: Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: only root can mount /dev/sdb1 on /mnt/media_sdb1

Comment: This is an right issue: either you use `sudo mount ...`, either you add the option `user` on your line in your fstab (man mount is your friend ;-) ).

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you're trying to mount:

```
/dev/sdb
```

i.e, the whole disk, rather than:

```
/dev/sdb1
```

i.e, the first partition on disk /dev/sdb.

cheers

sc.